# How to interpret the results of logistic regression in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, logistic-regression

Hello everyone, I'm new in this area, I wondered if anyone could help me understand the results of logistic regression.
I would need to understand if the independent variables can be used to make a good classification.

```html
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic -R 1.0E-8 -M -1 -num-decimal-places 4
Relation:     Train
Instances:    14185
Attributes:   5
              ATTR_1
              ATTR_2
              ATTR_3
              ATTR_4
              DEPENDENT_VAR
Test mode:    evaluate on training data

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

Logistic Regression with ridge parameter of 1.0E-8
Coefficients...
               Class
Variable           0
====================
ATTR_1        0.0022
ATTR_2        0.0022
ATTR_3        0.0034
ATTR_4       -0.0021
Intercept     0.9156


Odds Ratios...
               Class
Variable           0
====================
ATTR_1        1.0022
ATTR_2        1.0022
ATTR_3        1.0034
ATTR_4        0.9979


Time taken to build model: 0.13 seconds

=== Evaluation on training set ===

Time taken to test model on training data: 0.07 seconds

=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances       51240               72.2453 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances     19685               27.7547 %
Kappa statistic                         -0.0001
Mean absolute error                      0.3992
Root mean squared error                  0.4467
Relative absolute error                 99.5581 %
Root relative squared error             99.7727 %
Total Number of Instances            70925     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 1,000    1,000    0,723      1,000    0,839      -0,005   0,545     0,759     0
                 0,000    0,000    0,000      0,000    0,000      -0,005   0,545     0,305     1
Weighted Avg.    0,722    0,723    0,522      0,722    0,606      -0,005   0,545     0,633     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

     a     b   <-- classified as
 51240     5 |     a = 0
 19680     0 |     b = 1
```

In particular, I am interested in understanding the values of the coefficients and the odds-ratios.
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. To learn more about logistic regression in Weka you could try watching [this](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/data-mining-with-weka/0/steps/25398), and if you're new to data mining I recommend the full course. The confusion matrix in your output shows that this classifier is not doing a good job on your data because it is predicting that almost every instance belongs to class `a`, when 19680 of them should be `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

Odds ratios and coefficient values are proportional to another, and can be calculated from each other.

For attribute1 , `exp(0.0022) = 1.002`

For doing more calculations and fitting/predicting, coefficients are "better". However the coefficients are values that must be plugged into `exp(x)` functions and are somewhat difficult to "visualize in your head".

For human understanding, odds ratios are sometimes more convenient - easier to interpret/visualize, but you can't do certain calculations directly with them.

Weka does not know what you are more interested in, so it gives you both for convenience.

By the way, weka does *regularized* logistic regression 
(`Logistic Regression with ridge parameter of 1.0E-8`), so coefficients might differ slightly from those that a different software package might give you.